# What is the difference between 魂 and 魄?

Tags: meaning

Maybe this is a religious technical question and therefore a bit tricky. In English, soul and spirit are used more or less interchangeably, although their origins are dissimilar.

spirit: mid-13c., "animating or vital principle in man and animals," from Anglo-French spirit, Old French espirit "spirit, soul" (12c., Modern French esprit) and directly from Latin spiritus "a breathing (respiration, and of the wind), breath; breath of a god,"

soul:"A substantial entity believed to be that in each person which lives, feels, thinks and wills" [Century Dictionary], Old English sawol "spiritual and emotional part of a person,

In Chinese, is there a difference between 魂 and 魄？

魂: soul, spirit (We have 3)
 魄: soul, spirit (we have 7)

道家谓人有三魂

三魂：1.道家谓人有三魂：一曰胎光，二曰爽灵，三曰幽精，见《云笈七签》卷五十四。

道家谓人有七魄：

七魄：1.道家谓人有七魄，各有名目。第一魄名尸狗，第二魄名伏矢，第三魄名雀阴，第四魄名吞贼，第五魄名非毒，第六魄名除秽，第七魄名臭肺，见《云笈七签》卷五四。

Just got this phrase from reading 西游记：道士吓得三魂丢了七魄 which I would simply translate as 'very frightened, scared witless, frightened out of his mind'

Comment: That can't be translated into English, they're religious specific words. This happens a lot in human languages, nothing amazing. You already has an answer in your question, what are you asking for.

Answer (score 5):

This question is more advanced.

--

In short,

魂 is more related to the 陽 Yang side (the male, the bright, the sun side) of the spirit or soul.

魄 is more related to the 陰 Yin side (the female, the dark, the moon side) of the spirit or soul.

--

You may find the following texts valuable.

1) [道教原始的生命观认为，魂和魄一个属阴，一个属阳，一个主静，一个主动。阳魂就是思想，主动，是注意力，是对身体接触到外世界之后的第一反映，阴魄就是不变化的本源，主静，是对思想的承载，是一切万有的实质和内含。宇宙天地万物的总依赖。所以魂和魄之中，阴魄是体，阳魂为用。-- from www.zhihu.com/](https://www.zhihu.com/question/23474694)

2) [在中國哲學之中，魂魄陰陽對反，魂為陽性精氣，魄為陰性精氣](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AD%82%E9%AD%84)

3) "Within this ancient soul dualism tradition, every living human has both a hun spiritual, ethereal, yang soul which leaves the body after death, and also a po corporeal, substantive, yin soul which remains with the corpse of the deceased. Some controversy exists over the number of souls in a person; for instance, one of the traditions within [Daoism proposes a soul structure of sanhunqipo 三魂七魄; that is, "three hun and seven po". The historian Yü Ying-shih describes hun and po as "two pivotal concepts that have been, and remain today, the key to understanding Chinese views of the human soul and the afterlife."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hun_and_po)"

4) If you know the [Naruto story](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Narutopedia), the author also used the similar idea of 陰 Yin side and 陽 Yang side of souls as the two dual souls of the [Nine Tail beast](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kurama). See also the [Yin-Yang release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yin%E2%80%93Yang_Release) and [more](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode).

[image]

Comment: 谢谢你得努力！Now I have a lot more to read!

Answer (score 2):

Looking up the 1992 version of the [新华字典](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinhua_Zidian) published by the [商务印书馆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Press), on page 195 and page 367 we find respectively:

> 魂 hún ㄏㄨㄣˊ 旧日迷信的说法，指能离开肉体而存在的精神（(连) ~魄）：~不附体. 灵魂1.人的精神、思想方面活动的总称.2.事物的最精粹最主要的部分。
>
> 魄 (一) pò ㄆㄛˋ ❶ 迷信指依附形体而存在的精神（(连) 魂~）：丢魂落~. [...]

Therefore, 魂 refers to the 精神 that can exist without a living body, while 魄 refers to the 精神 whose existence depends on a living body.  Because they are two different kinds of 精神, they are sometimes used together, as in 魂魄 to mean all sorts of 精神.

Comment: So, maybe the West has just forgotten this distinction. 魂 soul: 能离开肉体而存在 spirit: 依附形体而存在. Reminds me of pulse, 诊脉. In the West we only know 1 pulse, 我听说中医认识3个诊脉。

Answer (score 1):

魂, as most agreed, refer to Soul. But 魄 , there is no english equivalent word to it. But the closest term, in my opinion, is Life Energy or Life Force. 魄 (Life Force) is also responsible for the manifestication of your physical body. You need both for a human to be completed. An entity with  魂(soul) but no 魄 (Life Force/body) can refer to as a ghost. An entity with 魄 (Life Force/body) but no 魂(soul) can become a zombie or in a vegetative state.