# How to understand 灵魂 sense of spirit?

Tags: translation

The words 灵魂 translates to 'soul' or 'spirit'. In English, the word 'spirit' can refer to the undefinable spiritual entity associated with the divine. I think that in Chinese, 灵魂 can refer to a person's innermost being and can be used in situations in situations of 'true love' referring to loving each other's 灵魂.

How can 灵魂 be used in sentences/sayings that distinguishes itself from the western understanding or meaning of 'spirit'?

Answer (score 2):

> How can 灵魂 be used in sentences/sayings that distinguishes itself from
>   the western understanding or meaning of 'spirit'?

We might also ask how you distinguish soul and spirit in English. If you are clear about that (a big if), you could find an answer to your question easily!

[Here](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-soul-and-spirit/) is a cheap and nasty explanation.

Have a look [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30517/what-is-the-difference-between-%E9%AD%82-and-%E9%AD%84/30521#30521) too.

> and can be used in situations in situations of 'true love' referring to loving each other's 灵魂.

Maybe the word you are looking for is soulmates? In the following sentences the bold text can be translated as soulmates.

我也不相信**灵魂伴侣**。
前卫网站《**灵魂伴侣**科学》报道称灵魂伴侣确实真实存在，而且可以被科学所证明。
昨日的挚友，今日的恋人，永远的**知己**
而且我希望全部你淑女也找你得不见**知音**
这个时候我真想找个**贴心人**说说心里话呀！

Comment: really good examples! except that 而且我希望全部你淑女也找你得不见知音 is not a meaningful sentence (though it appears on several Chinese websites). What about this example? 知音难觅，幸好有你，我不孤独 -- it's hard to find a soulmate. I'm lucky to have you. I am no longer alone.

Answer (score 1):

灵魂 could has multiple meanings depending on the context.
Have you watched bleach? yeah those hollows are the 灵魂 of a person after they died and Shinigami were suppose to help bring 灵魂 to the soul society.

Anyway, By order in which it is used most frequently, it means

1) Something that is not a matter that inhabit the body of a person where if gone the person would die. 人死灵魂飞天(One's soul will enter heaven when dead).

2)life : 这弱小的灵魂猫很快就会死去 (This fragile cat will die soon).

3) personality: 他有一个美丽的灵魂(He has a beautiful soul).

4) conscience : 只是一个出卖灵魂的方法(This is a way to sell one's conscience).

5) key, crucial things for deciding or leading： 施瓦辛格是健身的灵魂（Schwarzenegger is what made bodybuilding a popular sport).